# Tier 2 - ICT Short Term - Travel Date and CoS Expiry date

Tags: united-kingdom

I had applied for UK Tier 2 ICT short term visa in March 2015 and got it approved. However due to logistical reasons, I could not travel before the until date and am planning move next month. In my Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS), the job start date is specified as April. It is July now. So does it have any impact in immigration upon arriving in UK? Also is it mandatory for the CoS to be valid (not expired) when entering the UK because the visa is  approved?

Comment: This sounds (short term visa) like a question for Travel rather than Expatriates.

Comment: @ScottEarle This sounds (work visa) like a question for Expatriates rather than Travel.

Comment: T2 is an Expat topic, even T2 short-term because it requires working for the employer for the previous year.

Comment: If the CoS has expired, you should not try to enter the UK on a T2!

Answer (score 1):

In order to enter the UK on the Tier 2 Intra-Company Transfer, the Certificate of Sponsorship (CoS) must be valid; it cannot be expired. Additionally, you say ‘before the until date’ which implies that you’re referring to the validity period of the visa itself (*from* one date, *until* another date). If that is the case, and the Tier 2 visa validity period has passed, you and your company would have to repeat the visa process.